# multiple intents on different items of CustomListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onclicklistener

Whenever the user clicks the "phone icon" and *sms icon* an intend Dials a number or Sends an SMS. I don't know how to code my OnClickListener so that the two icons in the list view respond to the click event

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        ListView studentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        StudentAdapter adapter = new StudentAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, students);

        studentListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        studentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Student student = students.get(position);
                String url = student.getStudentNumber();

                           Student student = students.get(position);
            String url = student.getStudentNumber();
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", url);
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "your desired message");
            startActivity(smsIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this Sms intent works fine when I click anywhere of the item of my ListView but 
let's say there is a  with "sms icon" and **R.id.smsButton** in each item and I only want that to respond to the click event and start the intent, not any other Views in the Item of my CustomListView.
    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write click listeners in getView() method of adapter class itself

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
...
Button button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

         //do something

    }
});
...
return row;
```

}